# how do I use neo4j and Gremlin with nodejs

Tags: node.js, neo4j, gremlin

I would like to use the combination of neo4j, gremlin and nodejs. Is there any possibility?

Comment: You can use javascript with Gremlin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gremlin/v/3.3.3 more info in the reference documentation http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-javascript

Answer (score 0):

There a javascript driver for Neo4j that can be used in NodeJS. This driver allow you to make cypher queries to Neo4j.

You will find a lot of examples about it on the internet.

For Gremlin, can you tell why you want to use it with Neo4j ?

FYI, Cypher is a **declarative** langage (you  describe what you want), and Gremlin is **imperative** (you tell the compiler what you want to happen, step by step).

So "same same but different".

FYI, you can also transalte Cypher queries to  Gremlin : https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-gremlin

IMHO, to be **database agnostic** is a dream, even in the SQL world.
Products don't have exactly the same syntax, the same modelisation, the same protocol, ...

So if you want to be database agnostic, you need to take the common base of all the product, and so you level from below.

Comment: if I write my Queries in gremlin i can use same with Amazon Neptune or Azures cosmos  db.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is possible by installing plugin to Neo4j.

I myself fail to do it with Neo4j version 4.x but in theory it is possible for Neo4j v 2.x if you follow this old archived repo:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin

Also someone in issue page mention that the newer version of the plugin is now with Apache TinkerPop repo, but I didn't find good doc with it:
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/fc7f909a154b8c9e264580a0f73a3f0d0fb431a9/neo4j-gremlin